# How to retrieve data according to date range from mysql database using ajax in laravel php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I am building a simple holiday management system which allows the user to perform **CRUD** operation and to **retrieve** data according to a **date range**. However my CRUD operation is working as expected. But I am not able to **retrieve** the data according to user selected **date range from an ajax call**. Also this is the very first application that am developing by using laravel framework as well as ajax. I hope someone here may identify the reason for the problem am having with my code and will be able to help me.

**index.blade.php**

```
 <div class="input-group input-daterange">
       <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" readonly class="form-control">
       <div class="input-group-addon to-text"> to </div>
       <input type="text"  name="to_date" id="to_date" readonly class="form-control">
 </div>
```

**ajax** request handler method in **HolidayController.php**

```
    public function fetch_data(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()) {
            if($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '') {
                $data = DB::table('holidays')
                    ->whereBetween('startdate', 
                    array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))
                    ->get();
            }
            else {
                $data = DB::table('holidays')->orderBy('startdate', 'desc')
                ->get();
            }
            echo json_encode($data);

        }
    }
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::Resource('holiday', 'HolidayController');
```

make **ajax** request from **custom_script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var date = new Date();

    $('.input-daterange').datepicker( {
        todayBtn: 'linked',
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true
    });

    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

    fetch_data();

    function fetch_data(from_date = '', to_date = '') {
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('holiday.fetch_data')}}",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date, _token:_token
            },
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data) {
                var output = '';
                $('#total_records').text(data.length);
                for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
                    output += '<tr>';
                    output += '<td>' + data[count].id + '</td>';
                    output += '<td>' + data[count].firstname + '</td>';
                    output += '<td>' + data[count].lastname + '</td>';
                    output += '<td>' + data[count].startdate + '</td>';
                    output += '<td>' + data[count].enddate + '</td></tr>';
                }
                $('tbody').html(output);
            }
        })
    }

    $('#filter').click(function() {
        var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
        var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
        if(from_date != '' && to_date != '') {
            fetch_data(from_date, to_date);
        }
        else {
            alert('Both Date is required');
        }
    });

    $('#refresh').click(function() {
        $('#from_date').val('');
        $('#to_date').val('');
        fetch_data();
    });

});
```

Comment: Problem solved and this is working as I expected. The issue was I was trying to send AJAX in a separate .js file and there {{ }} wasn't working. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with `query`,unless `$request->ajax()` might remove for now. And change your blade file as follows,`input` type should be `date`, not `text` and remove `readonly` attribute.

```
<input type="date" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control">
   <div class="input-group-addon to-text"> to </div>
<input type="date"  name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control">
```

And make sure that `date` data is valid data with database

**For demonstration**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    function fetch_data(from_date = '', to_date = '') {
        if(from_date != '' && to_date != '') {
               console.log(from_date+' | '+to_date)
        }
       
    }

    $('#filter').click(function() {
        var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
        var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
        if(from_date != '' && to_date != '') {
            fetch_data(from_date, to_date);
        }
        else {
            alert('Both Date is required');
        }
    });

    $('#refresh').click(function() {
        $('#from_date').val('');
        $('#to_date').val('');
        fetch_data();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
       <input type="date" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control">
       <div class="input-group-addon to-text"> to </div>
       <input type="date"  name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control">
       <button id="filter">filter</button>
       <button id="refresh">refresh</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. How can I print the data within a loop to a table here?

Comment: in your controller `echo json_encode($data);` change to `return response($data)`

Comment: I am getting the response correctly, now I want to print them.

Comment: Without knowing your response data structure,its tough to give you solution.So,with your data object,ask different question.As you implemented on your `js` file `for` loop -this would be the process.But why don't you get printed them,don't get it here.However, if you think this is your question's answer,please mark it as answer.

Comment: No, now I am not receiving any responses. Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59700663/how-to-retrieve-data-in-a-date-range-from-mysql-database-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First of all, you can't use `{{ route('holiday.fetch_data')}}` inside your **.js file**. Use the simple route by typing the `url` or somehow, retrieve route from .blade.php file into .js file. e.g. using data-* attributes.

in `#filter` element pass the route with `date-route="{{ route('holiday.fetch_data') }}"`

and afterwards, in `$('#filter').click(function()` do

```
var route = $(this).data('route');
```

**2.** Please make sure your ajax request reach in your `fetch_data` in your Controller. In order to do that, just write inside your `fetch_data`

```
dd($request->all());
```

If you get the requests from ajax, means that your connections with `fetch_data` work just fine.

**3.** Try **parsing** the dates with `Carbon`, as I'm doing right below. Also, remove `$request->ajax()` and **return json data** with `return`.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function fetch_data(Request $request)
{     
   if($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '') {
        $from = Carbon::parse($request->from_date)->toDateString();
        $to = Carbon::parse($request->to_date)->toDateString();

       $data = DB::table('holidays')->whereBetween('startdate',[$from, $to])->get();
   }else {
       $data = DB::table('holidays')->orderBy('startdate', 'desc')->get();
   }

   return json_encode($data);
}
```